# capturing a text/word from a wegpage and importing it to csv file using javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, import

This code works great, button that imports data to csv file however const text and error handling is not working. Basically what I need is to capture words from a webpage, for example from this code, I wanted to capture the word "Google". It works but if i put other word that is not in the webpage, error handling is not working and it's capturing whatever word I put in const text.

Also, i wanted to capture words, is there a way can separate it with different headers per column?

I wanted a result like below:

```
Word1    Word2           Word3
Google   Google Search   I'm Feeling Lucky
```

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Text to CSV
// @namespace    http://your-website.com
// @version      1.0
// @description  Capture words from Google's webpage and export it to a CSV file
// @author       Your Name
// @match        https://www.google.com/*
// @grant        GM_download
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Function to capture the words from the webpage
    function captureTextFromGoogle() {
        const text = ("Google", "Google Search", "I'm Feeling Lucky");

        return text;

    }

    // Function to export the captured text to a CSV file
    function exportToCSV(text) {
        // Create a CSV content
        const csvContent = `"Word","Word2","Word3"\n"${text}"`;
        console.log(csvContent);
        // Create a Blob containing the CSV data
        const blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/csv' });

        // Create a download link and trigger the download
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = 'captured_text.csv';
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }

    // Create a button to trigger text capture and export
    const captureButton = document.createElement('button');
    captureButton.textContent = 'Export Data to CSV';
//    captureButton.style.position = 'fixed';
//    captureButton.style.top = '350px';
//    captureButton.style.right = '230px';
    captureButton.style.zIndex = '9999';
    captureButton.style.padding = '10px';
    captureButton.style.border = '1px solid #000';
    captureButton.style.backgroundColor = '#0077b6';
    captureButton.style.color = '#fff';
    captureButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    document.body.appendChild(captureButton);

    captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        try {
            // Capture the text from the webpage
            const capturedText = captureTextFromGoogle();

            // Export the captured text to a CSV file
            exportToCSV(capturedText);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it (change the mock data to match expected output) so we have a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for responding. how do i change it to the expected output? basically when you click the button, it will export it to a csv file and whatever you put in this function captureTextFromGoogle() {const text = "Google"; it will import it to that file. Sorry i'm beginner on this languange. Thank you.

Comment: Change `const text = "Google";` to match `Word1 Word2 Word3 Google Google Search I'm Feeling Lucky`

Comment: @mplungjan I edited the snippet and columns Word Word2 and Word3 works fine on the csv file. However, function captureTextFromGoogle isn't working as expected. It only captures "I'm Feeling Lucky", seems it's only capturing one word. I wanted it to match every column. Word Google Word2 Google Search Word3 I'm Feeling Lucky. Thanks for helping, appreciate it.

Comment: Also, is there any element on the webpage that I need to call since whatever text or word I put in from this function captureTextFromGoogle(), that will be captured and imported to csv file. Somehow static word is happening.

Comment: Wrong brackets. You need an array: `const text = ["Google", "Google Search", "I'm Feeling Lucky"];`

Comment: @mplungjan, I did try this but all the words in the bracket will only be in one column. In this example, Google,Google Search,I'm Feeling Lucky will only be in Word column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array and you need to quote the content but you need to REMOVE the quotes in the literal:

```
function captureTextFromGoogle() {
    const list = ["Google", "Google Search", "I'm Feeling Lucky"];
    return list.map(word => `"${word}"`).join(",");
}

// Function to export the captured text to a CSV file
function exportToCSV(text) {
    // Create a CSV content
    const csvContent = `"Word","Word2","Word3"\n${text}`;
```

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Text to CSV
// @namespace    http://your-website.com
// @version      1.0
// @description  Capture words from Google's webpage and export it to a CSV file
// @author       Your Name
// @match        https://www.google.com/*
// @grant        GM_download
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Function to capture the words from the webpage
    function captureTextFromGoogle() {
        const list = ["Google", "Google Search", "I'm Feeling Lucky"];
        return list.map(word => `"${word}"`).join(",");
    }

    // Function to export the captured text to a CSV file
    function exportToCSV(text) {
        // Create a CSV content
        const csvContent = `"Word","Word2","Word3"\n${text}`;
        console.log(csvContent);
        // Create a Blob containing the CSV data
        const blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/csv' });

        // Create a download link and trigger the download
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = 'captured_text.csv';
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }

    // Create a button to trigger text capture and export
    const captureButton = document.createElement('button');
    captureButton.textContent = 'Export Data to CSV';
//    captureButton.style.position = 'fixed';
//    captureButton.style.top = '350px';
//    captureButton.style.right = '230px';
    captureButton.style.zIndex = '9999';
    captureButton.style.padding = '10px';
    captureButton.style.border = '1px solid #000';
    captureButton.style.backgroundColor = '#0077b6';
    captureButton.style.color = '#fff';
    captureButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    document.body.appendChild(captureButton);

    captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        try {
            // Capture the text from the webpage
            const capturedText = captureTextFromGoogle();

            // Export the captured text to a CSV file
            exportToCSV(capturedText);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: thanks it works now. just have to get rid the captured " in the Word and Word 3 Column but words are now separated and matched. Thanks for your help :) Appreciate ti.

Comment: It's a bit much but I wanted to ask how do I go over searching a text in a webpage and import that in the csv file. cause this code is importing whatever I text or word put iin the function.

Comment: If you give me some actual examples and expected output I can take a look. Please update the question with this. What you have now as example (that I just formatted) does not explain what you just asked

Comment: If "Word","Word2","Word3" are headers just do 

`const csvContent = \`Word,Word2,Word3\n${text}\`;`

Comment: Thanks will post another question. Thanks for the help, this is so interesting to learn.